# Issues with formatting header in R prior to using plot() function

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, dataset

I have a data set that I've successfully read into **R**. It's a simple `data.frame` with ONE ROW of data (I'm not sure how many columns, but its in the hundreds). It was read with column headers, but no row labels. So the data set looks something like this:

> df=structure(list(X500000 = 0.0958904109589041, X1500000 = 0.10958904109589, X2500000 = 0.10958904109589, X3500000 = 0.164383561643836, X4500000 = 0.136986301369863, X5500000 = 0.205479452054795, X6500000 = 0.136986301369863, X7500000 = 0.0273972602739726, X8500000 = 0.0821917808219178, X9500000 = 0.178082191780822), .Names = c("X500000", "X1500000", "X2500000", "X3500000", "X4500000", "X5500000", "X6500000", "X7500000", "X8500000", "X9500000"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 79L)

Except that it is MUCH LARGER (I don't know if it matters, but it has around 300 columns going across). I'm trying to plot it so that the X##### labels are on the x axis, and the value of each data point is plotted on the y axis (say like a scatter plot on excel or even a line graph). Doing just plot(df) gives me an extremely bizarre graph that makes no sense to me (a bunch of boxes each with a dot right in the centre and no labels?).

I have a feeling it might work if I were to transform the data frame into a vector by removing the headings and then adding x-axis labels individually afterwards and doing a plot() on the vector, but if there is a way of avoiding that it would be great....

Comment: Please use the function dput to put a reproducible example in your question.

Comment: have you read the 'plot' help page?

Comment: yea I've read the plot help page. I know there's two ways to use plot(), one where you explicitely state x, y i believe. But I don't know how to extract that from my data. Plot(data) seems to work if my data was a linear vector, but I'd like not to format it into that if I can help it.
Also, you want me to use dput for the entire data frame? It's literally 300+ columns... or did you mean the graph that comes out of my plot() function that I'm getting thus far?

Comment: 1/ maybe use dput to produce a small example as the one you've put in your questions. The number of columns is not the issue here. 2/ In your case you have to specify x and y in the plot call, as there is no special method defained for plotting this type of data.frame. You can create one but that would be in a second time

Comment: dput gave me :
structure(list(X500000 = 0.0958904109589041, X1500000 = 0.10958904109589, 
    X2500000 = 0.10958904109589, X3500000 = 0.164383561643836, 
    X4500000 = 0.136986301369863, X5500000 = 0.205479452054795, 
    X6500000 = 0.136986301369863, X7500000 = 0.0273972602739726, 
    X8500000 = 0.0821917808219178, X9500000 = 0.178082191780822), .Names = c("X500000", 
"X1500000", "X2500000", "X3500000", "X4500000", "X5500000", "X6500000", 
"X7500000", "X8500000", "X9500000"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 79L)
 is that what you're looking for? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I have edited your question. Now can you precise in it what you have tried? Is it plot(df) ? Your question must be as precise as possible and contain reproducible code so that people can help you. Your question was to evasive.

Comment: @RockScience Do you know how I might specify the x and y? The X-axis labels are my current column headers. I've tried every combination of x = header / x = data(header) / x = data[1,].. nothing seems to be working...
and yes, I have tried plot(df), which gave me this really bizarre graph that isn't at all what I want. I can't really explain what this graph is as I have never seen that kind of output in my life before. Sorry if I'm not being too clear

Comment: is class(df[1,]) numeric? Is class(header(df) numeric? etc... You need to pass a vector of numeric to plot

Comment: @RockScience So I did what you did in your answer... and it worked brilliantly... I have no idea what is actually happening in: 
substr(names(df),2,nchar(names(df)))
but I think if I stare at it long enough and help() every function there... I might be able to trace it out or something haha... thanks so much for your help though!!

Comment: it just extracte the names, then removes the first character (X) then converts to a vector of numerics

Comment: Please approve my answer if you agree with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in '?plot', 'x' and 'y' must be two vectors of numerics, of same size:

```
df=structure(list(X500000 = 0.0958904109589041, X1500000 = 0.10958904109589, X2500000 = 0.10958904109589, X3500000 = 0.164383561643836, X4500000 = 0.136986301369863, X5500000 = 0.205479452054795, X6500000 = 0.136986301369863, X7500000 = 0.0273972602739726, X8500000 = 0.0821917808219178, X9500000 = 0.178082191780822), .Names = c("X500000", "X1500000", "X2500000", "X3500000", "X4500000", "X5500000", "X6500000", "X7500000", "X8500000", "X9500000"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 79L)    


plot(x=as.numeric(substr(names(df),2,nchar(names(df)))), as.numeric(df), xlab="This is xlab", ylab="This is y")
```